# HTTP Commands via Jquery

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I've been asked how we can send and receive HTTP requests to trigger a Mobile Text billing service.  The billing service has no webservice to respond/trigger these message and will only take requests from a whitelisted IP.  Therefore I assume we need a server side web service written that can handle a client request - trigger a billing message and return a reply to the client jquery/ajax.

This is coming from a fron-end developer with limited back end knowledge though!  Therefore does anyone agree with my assumption - before I respond!?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Sorry, this is too vague to really answer. You simply want something that can make HTTP requests? That's virtually anything that can connect to a network...

Comment: Your assumption is correct. And not just because of the whitelist (although this is one very good reason) but also because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Unless the destination server implements some kind of JSONP gateway and does not have IP-based restrictions, the *only* way to implement this is to write some middleware that will sit on your server, accept AJAX requests and forward them on to the destination, using something like [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 0):

A webService is  most prefferable. it  gives more flexibility for future changes on the front end architechture (or type)